# "ValueError: need more than X value to unpack" the pythonic way to iterate incomplete tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list of images that I want to generate a row of 3 in html for. 
I packed the list of images in tuples of 3. 
THIS GIVES INTENDED OUTPUT STILL! but i'd like to have it correct and correctly done the pythonic way.

***I believe it's because I have a list of images not divisible by three so it throws an error when there's a tuple with not three images inside it.***

How would I suppress this error because this is still working. Or how do I write my code cleaner to not produce this error and still have the same results?

Keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "images.py", line 31, in main
    for i,j,k in images:
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "images.py", line 31, in main
    for i,j,k in images:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Code:

```
    images = [images[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(images), 3)]
    html = title+".html"
    with open(html, "w") as post:
        post.write(title+'\n\n')

        for i,j,k in images:
            post.write('<div class="row">\n')
            post.write('<div class="col-md-4"><img src="'+  i["link"][:-4]+'m'+i["link"][-4:]  +'" alt="ChokeOuT" /></div>\n')
            post.write('<div class="col-md-4"><img src="'+  j["link"][:-4]+'m'+j["link"][-4:]  +'" alt="ChokeOuT" /></div>\n')
            post.write('<div class="col-md-4"><img src="'+  k["link"][:-4]+'m'+k["link"][-4:]  +'" alt="ChokeOuT" /></div>\n')
            post.write('</div>\n')
```

Comment: Well, you should strip `images` from the remainder in division by 3, process `images` like you already do, and handle the remainder separately. But I think you should be using an HTML template engine like jinja2 for this particular task

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists which have 3 element in them.

**Try:**

```
for image in images:
    for i,j,k in image:
        ...
```